# Is there any downside to declaring a struct containing a single array as packed?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, struct, alignment

I have a class that consists internally of just an array, e.g.:

```
class foo {
public:
    // methods
private:
    int myarray[10];
};
```

Elsewhere I have a packed struct (GCC extension) that contains a foo:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) bar {
    foo x;
};
```

But GCC complains that 'foo' isn't packed, so bar isn't packed. Now, if I make foo packed as well then GCC's error goes away. I intend to use foo in contexts other than being inside packed structs though, so for now I have two versions of foo, Foo and PackedFoo. However, seeing as they each only contain an array, and AFAIK there is no such thing as an 'unpacked array' in C++, is there any harm in me just having Foo and giving it the packed attribute? Will it somehow slow down the code GCC generates when I use Foo outside packed structs?

Comment: Why don't you stop packing `bar`? That seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: I'm using bar for parsing a wire format.

Comment: Then you need to pack everything that it contains!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But a packed array is meaningless. All arrays are packed in C/C++.

Comment: That's right. So why are you not prepared just to pack everything that is going to go on the wire.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As I stated in the question, I'm using the class in places where it's part of a packed struct and other places where it isn't. Although there /shouldn't/ be any functional difference, since arrays in C are always packed, I wanted to be sure the compiler won't automatically assume it can't do optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have ints (or arrays of ints) in your struct then packing it doesn't make much sense. I'd expect it to be harmless.

Likewise, if you only have `foo` in `bar`, then packing that will be pointless. I presume you've simply elided the rest of the contents?

Anyway, the answer to your question is that a packed struct (where packing it did have some effect) *will* cause the program to run slower. If it didn't, there'd be no point in having 'unpacked' structs. That might not be harmful if it's not in a performance critical section of your program though.

You can't mix and match though - you can't access a struct as packed in one place, and unpacked in another. That just won't work.

It's also unsafe to use packed structs in application APIs or networking, unless you're very sure what it'll do. The layout of packed structs is not standardized, although it's usually quite predictable.

Comment: Actually, the layout of neither packed nor unpacked structs is standardized, although they are both usually predictable.

Comment: @Rob the layout of structs is defined by the ABI, along with parameter passing conventions and all the other gubbins needed to make binaries compatible. If it weren't there'd be big trouble. Of course, It's possible (probable) that some ABIs also define the packed struct layout, but I wouldn't bet on it in platform independent code.

Comment: If the layout of structs is defined by (necessarily platform-*dependent*) ABI, then one must not rely upon that either in platform-*independent* code. The layout of neither packed nor unpacked structs are defined in any platform-independent standard.

Comment: I don't think the answer depends on the type of array inside foo. I think the question is essentially, is sizeof(foo) going to be the same regardless of whether foo is packed? When foo only contains an array, I don't see how, so I think it's safe to just always mark it as packed, but I'm afraid GCC will assume (wrongly) that it can't do optimizations.

Comment: @Rob: Right, cross platform code can't assume anything, but platform *independent* code where the *whole program* runs on that platform (i.e. I'm talking about shared libraries and such) then you can rely on the ABI - that's the whole point.